# Pubnub Subscribe PHP, apache restarts

Tags: php, apache, pubnub

So going by [PubNubs documentation for PHP](http://www.pubnub.com), if you do this:

```
$pubnub->subscribe('my_channel', function($message) {
    var_dump($message);  ## Print Message
    return true;         ## Keep listening (return false to stop)
});
```

The script is supposed to stay subscribed and keep listening for new pushes. However, if Apache is restarted then the script will stop and therefore stop receiving pushes.

I need a way to have a PHP to script always listening for pushes, regardless of Apache restarting, or even the server itself restarting. I need something that will re-run the script after a restart, or maybe a whole new different approach to this problem. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you run in a web context, all HTTP libraries will be bound to the existence of that web context. So if you restart Apache, yes, it will die, and restart again when Apache restarts.

You have another option however, which is to run the PHP client as a stand-alone PHP long running process, such as via a shell script, or via some sort of queuing mechanism.